# How to upload/run custom Windows Application on Azure Remote App

Tags: azure, winapp, remoteapp, custom-application

I am working with Azure Remote App service. I can already use the default published applications on Remote App collection. But I want to upload my own windows application on Remote App collection but have no clue on how to do that.
Could some one guide me to some good resource or a direct way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to create a template image with your custom application in it and then use that image to create an Azure RemoteApp collection.

To create a template image with your custom application, you can follow these steps: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-image-on-azurevm/ (basically, create Azure VM, install your app on the VM, sysprep, save the image to Azure RemoteApp)

Then, your image will appear in the list of images when creating a collection and you can follow the steps here to create a cloud collection: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-create-cloud-deployment/ (pick the aforementioned image)

We have more documentation about the service here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/remoteapp/ and we have other means of support here: https://www.remoteapp.windowsazure.com/en/support.aspx

/cd

P.S.: I work on Azure RemoteApp

Comment: Found that out and created a new Remote App collection based off new custom image created from Azure VM. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi David. I followed all the steps you mentioned, I created a new Custom Image based off Azure VM. Captured the image and imported in to template gallery of Remote Apps. But when I try to create a new Remote app collection my custom image is not visible in Template Image drop down. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I noticed that I need to pick the same "Region" where I created my image ,then it appears in the template drop down